# How to parse messages from Kafka __consumer_offsets topic

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm using kafka-tool v 2.0.1 (http://www.kafkatool.com/) to interact with kafka and I can easily see messages in the __consumer_offsets topic but I'm unable to understand what the messages are. The Keys, when read as a string, look perfectly normal (their values are the names of my consumer groups).

The messages, however, are junk when viewed as strings so I'm guessing I need to parse and/or decompress the long byte array but I'm not sure how. In the docs (https://kafka.apache.org/0110/documentation.html#impl_zkconsumeroffsets) I see that they are usually compacted but I don't really know anything beyond that.

Comment: The topics being compacted simply means they only retain the last value of a given key. It does not affect the contents of the messages.
But why do you want to read this topic? It's supposed to be a system topic that you don't need to use directly. Maybe you're asking the wrong question. If you explain the reason for trying to read the offsets topic, maybe we can point you in a different direction towards your end goal